# How to change a text box to visible depending on what item is selected in a drop down menu?

Tags: php, javascript, html, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I have a drop-down menu with a list of school subjects in it, the last option is "Add New Subject" so when the user selects that option, I need a text box to appear.

My HTML form looks like this: (I have only included the relevant bits, there is a bit more stuff on it.

```
<form method="post" action="createQuestion.php" name="cq">
  <select name="subject" id="subject">
    <option value="biology">Biology</option>
    <option value="maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="economics">Economics</option>
    <option value="newSub" <?php if($subject == "newSub1") { echo "SELECTED"; } ?>>
      Add New Subject
    </option>
  </select> 
  <input type="text" name="newSubtxt" ID="newSubtxt" style="visibility:hidden"> 
</form>
```

I have spent ages trying to get this to work with javascript, and I just can't get it to work at all.

This is the js I wrote, but doesn't work

```js
function addSubject(){
  const newSub = document.getElementById('newSub').name;
  const selectedSubject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
  if (selectedSubject === newSub){
    document.getElementById(newSubtxt).style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

I would be so grateful if someone could help me out with the javascript, so that it will work. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your invisible input to:

```
<input type="text" name="newSubtxt" id="newSubtxt" style="display: none" />
```

and your js:

```
function addSubject() {
    var selectedSubject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
    if (selectedSubject == 'newSub') {
        document.getElementById('newSubtxt').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgAmt/).

Answer (score 2):

Change the style of textbox with

```
<input type="text" name="newSubtxt" ID="newSubtxt" style='display:none;'>
```

I have used jQuery (javascript library) to solve your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#subject').change(function (){
    if($('#subject').val()=='newSub')
        $('#newSubtxt').show();
    else
        $('#newSubtxt').hide();
    });
});
```

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gTvdz/)